# php doesnt connect with mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to web design, I'm using sublime text editor for PHP and MAMP server. When I run my page in browser, I think MYSQLdatabase is connected but I didn't get correct output. My PGM is below:

basicform.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
</head>
<body>
    <Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="submitForm.php">

        <INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="username" Name ="username">
        <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Login">
    </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

submiteForm.php

```
<?PHP
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else echo "success";

mysql_select_db("innowell",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo $result;

$username = $_POST['username'];

if ($username == "letmein") {
    print ("Welcome back, friend!");
} else {
    print ("You're not a member of this site");
}

?>
```

Output:

> success  Resource id #3  You're not a member of this site.

what is the error in my pgm.can anyone help me to get solution?

Comment: Your are not fetching the result.

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs.

Comment: Congratulations, that output proves your code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you tried to dump the post variable to see what has been passed to the script?

Comment: it hurts me when i see people still using `mysql_*` functions... stop using them! they are outdated!

Comment: @fred-ii- thanks for the feed i am deleting my answer. as i did not notice op is mixing mysql and mysqli_

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Just modify your answer, it won't take much.

Comment: yes...i got output like this : success   Smith
You're not a member of this site

Answer (score 1):

You are presently mixing MySQL APIs, they (`mysql_` and `mysqli_`) functions do not mix together.

Use like this, take a look on [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

```
//conection: 
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mydb") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 

//consultation: 

$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 

//display information: 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
   echo $row["name"] . "<br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','innowell') or die(mysqli_error($con));

$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($con));

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); 

//display information: 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
   echo $row["ColumnName"] . "<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: is some thing wrong in the answer please let me know Thanks

Comment: OP is mixing MySQL APIs. You did not make the right changes.

Comment: @Fred-ii Thank you very much. i deleting it as its wrong. i did not notice before my bad Thanks for answering.

Comment: i got output which i want

Comment: anu thanks i updating my answer as well if you got the out please accept the solution. Thanks and @fred-ii- thanks for the suggestion. to update my answer

Comment: In the world where common sense is a super power, we still get to see the blind leading the deaf through the jungle full of tigers. Amazing.

Comment: @N.B. i know what you are saying and why you are saying. But it still funny.

Comment: @anul see the updated answer, this is the right way of doing it. and if i helped you please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either use mysql or mysqli

and update like below:

```
            $db = mysql_select_db("innowell",$con) or die(mysql_error());
            $query = "SELECT name FROM employees";
            $result = mysql_query($query,$db);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $name = $row["name"];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    -----basicform.html----
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>A BASIC HTML FORM</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="form1" method="POST" action ="submitForm.php">

    <input type="text" value="username" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" name = "submit1" value="Login" />

    </form>

    </body>
    </html>

                    \\submitForm.php\\

    <?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$con) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
} else {
    echo "success";
}
mysql_select_db("innowell", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$query    = "SELECT * FROM employees where username='" . $username . "'";
$result   = mysql_query($query);


if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {

    print("Welcome back, friend!");

} else {

    print("You're not a member of this site");

}

?>
```

Comment: I am assuming that you have field `username` in table `employees`.